# Che significa "mica"?

Tags: translation, word-meaning

Sto leggendo un libro, e ho incontrato la parola "mica". Che significa?  In Google Translate, la traduzione è la stessa parola e credo che significhi "torta". Ecco un esempio del libro:

```
Mica la faccio saltare in aria
```

Ho pensato che questa parola significhi lo stesso di "forse", ma questa è solo un'ipotesi.

Comment: Ah, è vero, se n'era già parlato: non me lo ricordavo.

Comment: Nota che "mica" ha una certa connotazione informale, non e' un sostituto "neutro" di "non".
In inglese quella frase si renderebbe con probabilmente "ain't gonna blow it up" o qualcosa del genere.

Comment: C'è una faccenda che mi ha sempre incuriosito riguardo alla struttura delle frasi contenenti "mica" come supporto alla negazione. La parola "mica" "michetta" è evidentemente settentrionale, ed i francesi hanno controllato buona parte del nord-italia fino a tempi recenti (metà '800). La struttura della frase negativa francese necessita di due elementi, esattamente come la frase negativa con "mica" a supporto: "je ne le sais pas" diventa "non lo so mica". La differenza è che uno è francese corretto, e l'altro italiano quasi informale ("mica" in questa accezione è quasi dialettale)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In origine “mica” significava “briciola”[1] e quindi “cosa piccolissima, quasi inesistente”. Lo si è poi cominciato a usare per rafforzare una negazione: «Non gliel'ho detto io.» -> «Non gliel'ho detto mica io.»

Spesso si usa anche da solo con valore negativo, come nel tuo esempio, che si potrebbe parafrasare «Non la faccio saltare affatto in aria», con in più un senso sottinteso quasi di «Per chi mi hai preso? Per uno che fa saltare per aria le cose?»

[1] È collegato etimologicamente con il settentrionale “michetta”, un tipo di panino.

Answer (score 1):

È una negazione, usata in dialoghi informali.  Può essere paragonato ad `affatto`. Diciamo che si usa in casi in cui si vuole sottolineare che l'eventualità che si sta descrivendo è praticamente impossibile, un evento irrealizzabile, un'esagerazione.

Comment: Attenzione: “[affatto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/affatto/)”, se non è associato a una negazione esplicita, **non** ha per niente un valore negativo.